# Can I do HA load balancing with ldirectord using only 2 servers?

Tags: load-balancing, heartbeat, ldirectord

I managed to set up a pacemaker-heartbeat cluster with a virtual IP address and a virtual instance of ldirectord, by gathering information from [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/high_availability_loadbalanced_apache_cluster_p3), [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuHighAvailabilityTeam/PacemakerHeartbeat) and [here](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.clusterlabs.org/doc/Cluster_from_Scratch.pdf). It seems that the proper way to use `ldirectord` is to have two load-balancing servers in front of two apache servers, then doing some arp tricks to get the apache servers to respond to the virtual IP.

According to [this blog post](http://gcharriere.com/blog/?p=339) (starting from "the traditional way"), these arp tricks will not work on a two-server setup, and may cause infinite loops. He then suggests some solution which I didn't fully understand, but is keepalived-specific.

So my question is: is it possible to use a clustered ldirectord to load balance between apache instances on the very same two servers? Like [this picture](http://gcharriere.com/blog/index.php?callback=image&pid=7&width=550&height=371&mode=)?

Answer (score 1):

Keepalived is a different project than heartbeat.

I usually use heartbeat for high availability. For heartbeat, you can define the resources that will be owned by one machine at a time. The VIP is one of these resources that can "move" from one machine to another. AFAIK, heartbeat package does not provide load balancing. To implement load balancing, I can use another package like haproxy.

Yes, it is possible to use the very same two servers to act as a load balancer and web server.

Comment: Thanks, I guess. My question was about ldirectord, but I'm also looking into haproxy as an alternative solution. It seems to be easier with haproxy, working on level 7 rather than 4, since no arp tricks are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use keepalived.

It's the preferred software nowadays, ldirectord is unmaintained for several years now.

And yes, it is possible to do run a Two-Node setup.

However every *real* cluster needs three nodes, at least.